# Vectorize quadratic expansion

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I have a matrix X with vectors in n columns. In my case this is a series of vectors in time (column 1 is t1, column 2 is t2 ...). I would like to return a new matrix Y such that for each X(:,i)

Y(:,i) = [ X(1,i)^2, X(1,i)*X(2,i), ... X(n-1,i)*X(n,i), X(n,i)^2 ];

Currently I do this by computing outer product X(:,i) * X(:,i)', then return upper triangular matrix using triu() and finally get nonzero elements of the result with nonzeros():

Y(:,i) = nonzeros( triu( X(:,i) * X(:,i)' ) );

I am still using for loop over columns. Is it possible to vectorize this nicely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind losing the `triu` part (that is, getting repeated values);

```
Y = reshape(bsxfun(@times, permute(X,[1 3 2]), permute(X,[3 1 2])), [],size(X,2))
```

To remove repeated rows of `Y`, corresponding to symmetric values of the `X`-row pairs (the equivalent of your `nonzeros(triu)`): precompute the pattern of rows to keep, and then use it to trim `Y`:

```
keep = nonzeros(triu(reshape(1:size(X,1)^2, size(X,1),size(X,1))));
Y = Y(keep,:);
```

Comment: Love this solution! In my application the number of rows = number of features. Therefore I am not very keen to see number of features explode even stronger. Is there possibility to know which are double rows and then remove duplicates?

Comment: @xeon Thanks. One-liners with `bsxfun` do have a certain charm :-) See edited answer regarding removing those rows

Comment: Thank you very much, this combo did the trick! I didn't see how the bsxfun() could be used here. Your solution is 4x faster than my solution with cellfun() which applies the expansion function columnwise. Definitely "Accept"!